# Codeigniter Helper Function

Tags: php, codeigniter, helper

I am having a strange problem with my Codeigniter Helper class. I have declared some functions in a helper. I have included the helper in autoload. Its running perfectly in local machine. But when I run it on live server,the helper functions are workng in controller, but in view its giving Fatal error: Call to undefined function strip_tags().

in helper file my_helper.php the function is :

```
function do_strip($text) {
    $text = strip_tags($text);
    $text = stripcslashes($text);       
    return $text; 
}
```

autoload.php :

```
$autoload['helper'] = array('url','form','my_helper');
```

in my view I have called :

```
<?=do_strip($someval)?>
```

Have missed something or done some mistake ? Can someone please help me on this.

Comment: use like this $autoload['helper'] = array('url','form','my');

Comment: also change the function name as "strip_tags" is PHP function

Comment: I have changed the function name to do_strip()  and gave $autoload['helper'] = array('url','form','my'); . The problem is when I call it in my view file its showing undefined.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

remove `helper` text in auto load :

```
$autoload['helper'] = array('url','form','my');
```

For more information, refer this [Link](http://codeboxlabs.com/create-helper-codeigniter/)